# How do I call/run a constructor I have written?

Tags: apex

I have written a constructor, which contains code to update the Subject field on the Case object.

However, I can't get the constructor to run. The debug logs from this particular constructor are not showing up. How do I run it? Thanks!

```
public class UserDevice
{
    public String deviceSerialNumber    { get; set; }

    // Attempt to call the below constructor
    UserDevice UserDevice = new UserDevice(deviceSerialNumber);

    // Pass the serial number to the constructor
    public UserDevice(String serialnumber)
    {

        // This code is NOT running, I can't see this debug message in the Debug Logs
        System.debug('TESTING: ' + serialnumber);

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this class? should be from a trigger most likely, please can you post the method you are using to call the class.

Comment: why are you calling the constructor of the class from within the class itself? If this is a VF custom controller, you can't pass arguments to its constructor, you'll need to use URL params to communicate to the constructor

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read up on the differences between [static and instance variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm).

With your current implementation, each `UserDevice` has a self instantiating property that is also of type `UserDevice`, which I would think would lead to infinite nesting. For instance, if I call

```
UserDevice device = new UserDevice(mySerialNumber);
```

then it will have the following properties:

```
UserDevice nested = device.UserDevice.UserDevice.UserDevice.UserDevice;
nested = nested.UserDevice.UserDevice.UserDevice.UserDevice.UserDevice;
```

I think the implementation would be more clear like so:

```
public class UserDevice
{
    public static UserDevice factory(String serialNumber)
    {
        return new UserDevice(serialNumber);
    }

    // this property should not be writeable outside this class
    public String deviceSerialNumber    { get; private set; }
    public UserDevice(String serialnumber)
    {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        system.debug(this.serialnumber);
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to get a `UserDevice` instance from somewhere else, the below should work:

```
UserDevice device1 = UserDevice.factory(mySerialNumber);
UserDevice device2 = new UserDevice(mySerialNumber);
```

If you are trying to define an empty constructor for some reason, the proper syntax would be:

```
public UserDevice()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Actually, you're thinking of a stack overflow. The moment you create a single record from the factory, it'd explode all over the stack. This is why you shouldn't initialize values outside of a constructor, because it's easy to build explosive code.

Comment: Probably the right term, but a factory method would not e susceptible to that as long as the object doesn't contain itself as a member that gets set on instantiation.

Comment: If it were meant to be used right, it'd be a static variable, for a "singleton" pattern. That's probably not the user's intent, so the original code is fairly nonsensical (perhaps their actual problem was oversimplified). I'm not disagreeing with you, simply stating what the original code would have done, had they got it working.

Answer (score 0):

which I would think would lead to infinite nesting.
For instance, if I call

`UserDevice device2 = new UserDevice(mySerialNumber);`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this is largely a duplicate of the existing answers from ~7 years ago (but with less information).

Answer (score -1):

Try changing code like below,

```
public class UserDevice
{
    public String deviceSerialNumber    { get; set; }

    // Attempt to call the below constructor
    public UserDevice(){
       this(deviceSerialNumber);
    }

    // Pass the serial number to the constructor
    public UserDevice(String serialnumber)
    {

        // This code is NOT running, I can't see this debug message in the Debug Logs
        System.debug('TESTING: ' + serialnumber);       


        //System.debug('Serial number:' + deviceSerialNumber);
        //CaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        //// Query for the contact, which has been associated with an account.
         // Using Subject field for testing.
        //Case queriedCase = [SELECT Case.Subject 
        //                          FROM Case 
        //                          WHERE  CaseNumber = '05235730'
        //                          LIMIT 1];

        //// Update the case serial #
        //queriedCase.Subject = deviceSerialNumber;

        //// 1. This call is to update the case
        //update queriedCase;

    }
}
```

But please note that constructor will be executed first. So value of `deviceSerialNumber` will be null in constructor always.

Comment: Hi Victor, I was going through the post and got curious about what's the difference here if we initiate the object the way you did. please explain . thanks a lot..

Comment: The default constructor sets the property to null. This code is therefore just inwfficient.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, you are right. It is just inefficient and property will be always null.